# Conditional onkeyup event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

Currently I'm using the following:

```
document.onkeyup = function (data) {
    if (data.key == 'Escape') {
        ClosePlayerMenu()
    }
};
```

However I'm having two separate menus. A PlayerMenu for normal users, and a Staff menu for Staff members. Everything works but I can't use the current code twice, one to close the Player Menu and one to close the Staff menu as it makes one of the two menus no longer close. So I'm trying to make the key conditional that if PlayerMenu is open, <kbd>ESC</kbd> will close it, if Staff Menu is open it will close that. What would be the best approach?

Comment: Look at `data.target` in the two situations you wish to distinguish.

Comment: Isn't there a method or variable eg. `playerMenu.isOpen` that you can check to close respective menu?

Comment: @danh target could be outside the open menu

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Currently there is no check function considering it just calls the function to close on key up